# "Пес" и "пасти"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Действительно ли слово "пес" происходит от слова "пасти" или мне это только показалось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово ПАСТИ 'присматривать за скотом и птицей во время выгона на подножный корм', 'припасать, беречь' (устар.) имеет праслав. происхождение Первонач., вероятно, значило «охранять, беречь», а затем «присматривая, кормить» (скот на пастбище). Ср. приставочное спасти «уберечь», «избавить от опасности»; лат. pasco «пасу», «кормлю», pastor «пастух», от него через нем. в рус. яз. пастор «священник протестантской церкви». От глаг. пасти образовано с суф. -ух сущ. пастух «тот, кто пасет скот»; с суф. -ырь — пастырь «пастух» (устар.), «священник».

ПЕС 'собака' - древн. слав. слово. Соврем. его форма развилась из др.-рус. песъ вследствие утраты ъ и перехода под ударением е в 'о (графич. ё) (в укр. пес звучит е). Др.-рус. песъ из праслав. рьsъ. В нем ь развился в е. Об исходном знач. этого слова существуют разные мнения. Одни полагают, что слово *рьsъ первонач. значило «сторож» (стада, двора и т. п.) и ставят его в этимол. связь с лат. specio «смотрю», авест. spasyeiti «наблюдает» и слав. пасти. Другие считают, что животное могло быть названо по окраске: «цветное, пятнистее». Древн.* рьsъ развилось из *pьbs(t)rъ>. Ср. др.-рус.* пестрый «пятнистый»; др.-инд. pingas, pingalas «красноватый, коричневатый»; pinkte «рисует, красит» (см. писать). Третьи находят возможным сравнивать слово песъ с др.-инд. pecus «скот»; лат. pecus «скот, домашнее животное», полагая, что пес был первым прирученным животным.

Как видите, согласно одной из версий слова ПЕС и ПАСТИ могут быть родственными.